# Sample Request for a REST-API in Java or PHP

Tags: java, php, rest

I am looking at extracting data from a survey tool using their API. Being fairly new to APIs, I went through their documentation, few videos and figured out a little of what's happening.

But along with the Method and Attributes, they also have a sample request in Java/PHP and a sample response. Now the sample response is the JSON file fomat I'm expecting back but what do I have to do with a sample response?

As in, from all the videos I have seen you call an API using a particular URL. What is this sample request used for? Is it for using it in your own code?

I know its quite a silly question but any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: You question isn't silly; more like: not making sense. No idea what you are asking ...

Comment: Alright. Here's another go at it.

Comment: What is the use of a sample request in an API documentation? Because i'm using the URL to do the work for me to get the sample response that it says it will give me.

Comment: @A_S It's so you can look at it and think "So that's what a valid request looks like. No wonder when I tried to send a request it didn't work, because I just sent some random garbage instead of a well formed request."

Comment: @Kayaman well,my request did work(i guess!) as I got a 200 code. but the response{} part of the response was blank.

Comment: Please dont put more information into comments; put them into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a system that manages "virtual machines" for you; and that offers an API like:

```
/system/create-new-virtual-machine

/system/{virtual-machine-id}/start
```

So: your client would first call the first API method to somehow define a new virtual machine (providing all the required data to create a configuration).

Obviously, when you create a new thing, that should result in a new URI; which you would use later on to make other calls. In our example, the create call would return 200 ... and give you the URI for the newly created vm within the result body.

Long story short: just think of your REST api as the interface of a component/module your code is dealing with. Some of the API operations just tell you "fine, I passed" ... but others will want to give you information back. And that is what you need the response body for.

Comment: Ah! I think I get it now! So all I have been doing with the URL is just doing a handshake with the Server I'm trying to access. In order to get the response I want (survey responses) I'll have to script it using Python or Java or PHP following the sample request they have suggested and run that module. Thanks a lot for your help. :)